# JLabel actionlistener, what to use? Automatic update labels

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlabel

I'm trying to update my `JLabel` objects when my GUI is running.
Have create 3 labels which contain text and some variables. These variables gets updated automatically when the program is running.

I want to make an `ActionListener` like the one you can make to a button, but without clicking to update the labels. I want it to update automatically every 1 sec.

**Some code of my label:**

```
powermessage = new JLabel("<html> Usage: " + kWh + " kWh <br> <br>" + message + "</html>");
```

Have before used this method (see under).

```
button.addActionListener(this);
```

This worked fine, but I don't want the user to click for the monitor to update.

Any one know a simple solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try it like this:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    powermessage.setText("myvaluegoeshere");
    }
});
myTimer.start();
```

Comment: Don't i have to add the actionlistener to a label first? or?

Comment: This is a Timer, not a Listener. Every 1000 milliseconds he will execute the code within.

Answer (score 0):

Create Timer and update JLabel.text property from within:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // update your labels here
    }
}, 1000,1000);
```

Comment: `// update your labels here`  No, update them from the EDT, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29535771/418556).

Comment: sorry, I am new on Stack Overflow and I didn't notice that it is possible to edit answer. You are also right about executing update in event thread.

Comment: *"executing update in event thread."*  It is **possible** to ensure the update of GUI components is done on the EDT (from a `Thread` that is not - like above), but it takes a few extra lines of code..